# Obtain equivalents of SelStart and SelLength from Internet Explorer_Server object

Tags: winapi, vb6, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to get the equivalent of VB's SelStart and SelLength properties from an Internet Explorer_Server object?

I've tried using SendMessage EM_GETSEL but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to query the `InternetExplorer_Server`'s HWND for its [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574.aspx) interface, and then you can use the browser's DOM interfaces to manipulate the browser content as needed:

[How to get IHTMLDocument2 from a HWND](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232)

[IHTMLDocument2::selection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752606.aspx)

Comment: The VB equivalent of your link is here FYI:
http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/iedom.shtml

Comment: Does the .Selection property reveal SelStart and SelLength equivalents? The properties I get are .clear, .createrange, .empty and .type - how do I use them to get what I'm after?

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869514.aspx) for `createRange()`, it says: "Creates a TextRange object from the **current text selection**".  Remember that a web browser is much more than just text, so there is no simple `SelStart` and `SelLength` value exposed. If you do an online search for "ihtmldocument2 selstart" for instance, you will find several different solutions for manually calculating the SelStart/SelLength values from a TextRange object.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code where you want to calculate SelStart and SelLength. Replace InternetExplorer_Server.hWnd with a handle to your object.

```
Dim DomObj As IHTMLDocument2
Dim SelObj As IHTMLTxtRange

Set DomObj = IEDOMFromhWnd(InternetExplorer_Server.hWnd)
Set SelObj = DomObj.selection.createRange
TextToCheck$ = DomObj.body.innerText
' Calculate SelLength...
SelLength = Len(SelObj.Text)
SelObj.moveStart "character", -Len(TextToCheck$)
' Calculate SelStart...
SelStart = Len(SelObj.Text)
```

Requires the following code in a Module:

```
Private Type UUID
  Data1 As Long
  Data2 As Integer
  Data3 As Integer
  Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any, ByVal fuFlags As Long, ByVal uTimeout As Long, lpdwResult As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ObjectFromLresult Lib "oleacc" (ByVal lResult As Long, riid As UUID, ByVal wParam As Long, ppvObject As Any) As Long


Public Function IEDOMFromhWnd(ByVal hwnd As Long) As IHTMLDocument2

Dim IID_IHTMLDocument2 As UUID
Dim hWndChild As Long
Dim lRes As Long
Dim lMsg As Long
Dim hr As Long

' Register the message
lMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")

' Get the object pointer
Call SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, lMsg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes)

If lRes Then
' Initialize the interface ID
With IID_IHTMLDocument2
   .Data1 = &H626FC520
   .Data2 = &HA41E
   .Data3 = &H11CF
   .Data4(0) = &HA7
   .Data4(1) = &H31
   .Data4(2) = &H0
   .Data4(3) = &HA0
   .Data4(4) = &HC9
   .Data4(5) = &H8
   .Data4(6) = &H26
   .Data4(7) = &H37
End With

' Get the object from lRes
hr = ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument2, 0, IEDOMFromhWnd)

End If

End Function
```